# Is there any way to reduce the size of bundle package in TideSDK?

Tags: size, bundle, tidesdk

i am using tideSDK 3.1.1-beta and tideSDK Developer 1.4.2.

i developed a Desktop application on linux 32 bit.

After packed my application as bundled package its **size is 35 MB.**
My application is very small so now **i want to reduce the size of application.**

**is there any way?** 
if way is there means **how to reduce it?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently TideSDK on Linux bundles the required dependency libraries like glib, poco, webkit etc. That's the reason the bundle size is much bigger. The size cannot be reduced atm because the thirdparty libs are older and TideSDK currently does not work with newer version of those libs.